# How and where is the slidechange event raised?

Tags: jquery-ui

I have a custom binding for Knockout which attaches to the "slidechange" event on a jquery UI slider.

What I can't figure out is where this event is raised - a text search for "slidechange" within the jquery UI source code pulls up nothing!

So I'm guessing this is a convention based approach - the question is: 
What is the convention with jquery UI for events?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `slidechange` event is fired whenever the position of the slider is changed by the user.  In the code if you look in the `_change` method in `jquery.ui.slider.js` this is the line of code that triggers the event.

```
this._trigger( "change", event, uiHash );
```

`_trigger` is a method in jQuery UI's widget factory that will prefix the first parameter with the widget's defined `widgetEventPrefix` (in this case `slide`).  Therefore when that line of code is invoked all handlers bound to the `slidechange` event will be triggered.

There are two ways to subscribe to the event.  One is by passing in a `function` in when creating the `slider`.

```
$('my-selector').slider({
    change: function() {
        console.log('change');
    }
});
```

The other is to subscribe to the `slidechange` event using jQuery's `bind` or `on` method.

```
$('my-selector').on('slidechange', function() {
    console.log('change');
});
```

You can see both of these events being fired in this example - http://jsfiddle.net/tj_vantoll/XUyKs/

jQuery UI's API site documents all events that each widget fires as well as provides examples how you can subscribe to them.  For example, here's the documentation on the `slidechange` event - http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#event-change.

Comment: widgetEventPrefix aha!!

I'm actually happily using the slider with knockout with a custom-binding I got from google - I am however, trying to build my own widget with custom events - see my other question if interested), and was trying to copy the slider custom-binding - it confused me that I couldn't find the event name in the source code - didn't think of looking for a prefix. Many thanks!